# What is the erb equivalent of macros in jinja2?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, jinja2

In jinja2 I can specify frequently used template code in macros, essentially like template functions:

```
{% macro input(name, value='', type='text', size=20) -%}
    <input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{value|e }}" size="{{ size }}">
{%- endmacro %}
```

and then use it like so:

```
{% input("hello") %}
```

Is there any way to accomplish something similar with erb templates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use lambdas/procs instead of methods then you can:

```
require 'erb'

doc = <<ERB
<% input = lambda do |name, value='', type='text', size=20| %>
  <input type="<%= type %>" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value || 'e' %>" size="<%= size %>">
<% end %>
<% input["hello"] %>
<% input["HELLO", 123, 'select', 50] %>
ERB

puts ERB.new(doc, 0, '>').result
# >>   <input type="text" name="hello" value="" size="20">
# >>   <input type="select" name="HELLO" value="123" size="50">
```

The problem is that erb (and erubis) create these strings by parsing the document and creating another piece of code in which the values inside and outside the tags are inverted. Then the template between the tags is just appended to some local variable. (there are actually ways around this, but you have to go somewhat deep, I've had to extend erubis before to get the alternative behaviour I wanted). When you create methods, that changes scope and the local variable can no longer be seen, so it gives you some obscure error `NameError: undefined local variable or method ‘_erbout’ for main:Object` When you use closures, the environment is captured, including the local variable, so you can then write to it.